# Python Equivalent to Perl's prove

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am working on a tdd project in python and I am looking for a quick way to run all unit tests in my t/ directory.  In perl this is easy:

```
$ prove -lvr t/
```

I am looking for the python equivalent.  It does not seem that nose has this functionality. I rolled a command line statement to do something like this:

```
for x in `find t/ | grep py`; do echo $x && python $x ; done
```

But this lacks flags like -l (include the local lib dir) and -v (verbose).   Does this or does this not exist in python?  I want a one liner like this:

```
$ pyprove -lvr t/
```

Comment: Does http://testoob.sourceforge.net/ fit your needs?

Comment: @DavidWilliams, the `prove -lvr .` did help me a lot after seeing post. This post deserve more attention, It is a great question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by running `python -m unittest discover -s t/`, which will [discover your unit tests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) and run them for you. It looks like there's a verbose flag, but I don't see a flag to include the local lib dir.

Comment: thanks for the command.  it still seems to not find them though:  `broadways-MacBook-Pro-2:dsa dwilliams$ python -m unittest discover -s test/

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`  my test directory looks like this `$ find test/  ... test/lib/company/product/subsystem/mytest.py`

Comment: Try running `python -m unittest discover -s -p 'test/*/*/*/*/*.py'` - you can configure patterns to use for the test files you want to run.

Answer (score 2):

Try [nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/1.3.0).  Add `-v` for verbosity, `-w` to specify search directories (ref: [usage](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)).

```
nosetests -v -w t/
```

Comment: `$ nosetests -v -w test/

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK`  

However I have tests a few directories deep in there

Comment: Sub-directories may need an `__init__.py` to be recognized as a python package; it can be an empty file (ref: [packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages))